# No Overload Version of Write

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, delphi-xe6

I am shareing a project with someone codeing in xe6, I am using xe2 version 16. I get this error

`There is no overloaded version of 'write' that can be called with these arguments`

at this code.

```
  {$IF CompilerVersion >= 19}
  // Modified code for Delphi XE5 & later
  tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, IndyTextEncoding.Default  );
  {$ELSE}
  // Original XE2 code
  tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, TIdTextEncoding.Default);
  {$IFEND}
```

I have also added `idGlobal` in the uses. Any other reason this would give error?

Comment: What is the type of `TheMsg`? Have you checked that appropriate overload fuction does exist in IdIOHandler.pas?

Comment: `IndyTextEncoding` is a function which takes at least one parameter for each of its overloads. However, I don't understand why to pass to the `AByteEncoding` parameter of the `Write` method a default encoding. It's an optional parameter which internally defaults to the same, to `IndyTextEncoding_Default` encoding. So if you really want to use that parameter, pass there `IndyTextEncoding_Default` instead.

Comment: Thanks TLama, also TheMsg was a `string`

Comment: @TLama i removed the IndyTextEncoding.Default from it, and was told it would not compile in XE6 .. sorry i think i said XE5 above

Comment: Also with the `IndyTextEncoding_Default` i still get same error.

Comment: `IndyTextEncoding_Default` and `TIdTextEncoding.Default` are not the same encoding. Use `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IndyTextEncoding()` is a series of overloaded functions, all taking an input parameter, all returning an `IIdTextEncoding` interface:

```
function IndyTextEncoding(AType: IdTextEncodingType): IIdTextEncoding; overload;
function IndyTextEncoding(ACodepage: Word): IIdTextEncoding; overload;
function IndyTextEncoding(const ACharset: String): IIdTextEncoding; overload;
{$IFDEF DOTNET}
function IndyTextEncoding(AEncoding: System.Text.Encoding): IIdTextEncoding; overload;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF HAS_TEncoding}
function IndyTextEncoding(AEncoding: TEncoding): IIdTextEncoding; overload;
{$ENDIF}
```

`IIdTextEncoding` does not have a `Default` property (or any other encoding type properties).  `IIdTextEncoding` was introduced to break away from Embarcadero's `TEncoding` class and simplify Indy's memory management of codepage/charset handlers.

In earlier versions of Indy, the `TIdTextEncoding.Default` property represented the OS default encoding.  The correct way to get the OS default encoding in the latest version of Indy is to use the `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault()` function:

```
function IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault: IIdTextEncoding;
```

Or the `IndyTextEncoding(IdTextEncodingType)` function with `encOSDefault` as the input parameter.

```
{$IF CompilerVersion >= 19}
// Modified code for Delphi XE5 & later
tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
// or: tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, IndyTextEncoding(encOSDefault));
{$ELSE}
// Original XE2 code
tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, TIdTextEncoding.Default);
{$IFEND}
```

The `IndyTextEncoding_Default()` function, by comparison, returns an `IIdTextEncoding` that represents Indy's default encoding that is specified in the `IdGlobal.GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable (7bit ASCII by default).

If you want to use something that works in both Indy versions without using an `{$IFDEF}`, use the deprecated `IndyOSDefaultEncoding()` function:

```
function IndyOSDefaultEncoding{$IFNDEF DOTNET}(const AOwnedByIndy: Boolean = True){$ENDIF}: IIdTextEncoding;
```

```
tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, IndyOSDefaultEncoding);
```

That being said, note that the OS default encoding varies from one machine to another, and from one platform to another.  You should not be using it as the byte encoding in communication protocols.  Use a standardized encoding instead, such as UTF-8.

Lastly, if you are going to use `{$IFDEF}` or `{$IF}`, Indy has its own `{$DEFINE}` statements in `IdCompilerDefines.inc`, and global version constants in `IdGlobal.pas`, that you can use to detect Indy versions.  You might consider using those instead of the `CompilerVersion` constant.  If you were to ever upgrade Indy in XE2, for example, then your code would break.  You should be checking for Indy versions, not Compiler/RTL versions, eg:

```
// Indy version constants were added in 10.5.9.4850
// TIdTextEncoding was replaced with IIdTextEncoding in 10.6.0.0
{$IF (gsIdVersionMajor > 10) OR ((gsIdVersionMajor = 10) AND (gsIdVersionMinor >= 6))} 
tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
{$ELSE}
tcpConnection.IOHandler.Write(TheMsg, TIdTextEncoding.Default);
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: Very nice,  Wanted to add even if i used `IndyTextEncodeing_OSDefalut` i still go the error.. it was not till i had it check indy version and not compiler version that it worked. Thanks Again.

Comment: well i lied, it no longer gave any errors till i tried to compile. `[DCC Error] ss_CommsBackEnd.pas(301): E2029 Expression expected but '=' found
[DCC Warning] ss_CommsBackEnd.pas(301): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
[DCC Warning] ss_CommsBackEnd.pas(301): W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
[DCC Error] ss_CommsBackEnd.pas(301): E2026 Constant expression expected`

Comment: @GlenMorse: `==` should be `=` in the `$IF` expression.

Comment: i fixed that,but still get `Constant expression exepected` and 3 warnings ` comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands` on this line `{$IF (gsIdVersionMajor > 10) OR ((gsIdVersionMajor = 10) AND (gsIdVersionMinor >= 6))}`

Comment: @GlenMorse: Works fine for me in XE2 without any warnings or errors, exactly as showed. I did not test it with XE6, but I can't imagine Embarcadero changed how `$IF` works (well, they did change `$IFEND` back to `$ENDIF` in XE3).